# Why is it "den zwei Autos" and not "die zwei Autos"?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

I've come across the sentence

> Ich stehe zwischen den zwei Autos

Google also gives me much more results when searching `den zwei Autos` than when searching for `die zwei Autos`.

I've also found lots of results for `den zwei Hunden`, `den zwei Steinen` etc.

Why is `den` used instead of `die`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The preposition *zwischen* governs dative, not accusative, when describing a position. It is accusative for a movement:

> Sie stellt sich zwischen die Autos. Jetzt steht sie zwischen den Autos.

This is the same for similar prepositions such as *in*, *auf*, *über*.