# Exactly how much movement needs to be implied by a sentence for the accusative case to be used?

Tags: grammatical-case

I was always taught that using a verb that implies movement automatically tiggers the accusative case for the direct object when used with certain prepositions.

For example, Germans say

> Ich gehe ins Bett.

rather than

> Ich gehe im Bett.

However I'm confused by exactly what degree of movement needs to be implied for this to hold true. Is there some kind of threshold that needs to be reached?

For example, let's take the sentence

> I look at the clock.

Would that be dative or accusative? To me it doesn't require a great deal of movement, but then I suppose you are moving your eyes. Is there a list of not quite so obvious verbs that also require the accusative?

Comment: It's less about movement and more about direction. There is another thread about this, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Check whether this answer helps: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/41849/35111

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wechselpräpositionen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41846/wechselpr%c3%a4positionen)

Comment: @DavidVogt and RalfFriedl have already pointed you towards a relevant answer for your question. In the case of your clock example, it's accusative: "Ich schaue auf die Uhr." You ask "wohin [schaust du]?" and not "wo"? (meaning it's a direction - and no location).

Comment: *I go to bed. – Ich gehe zu Bett.* Old-fashioned but valid German.

Answer (score 2):

As others had already pointed out, most of your question is covered in [this answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/41849/35111). For verbs as *gehen*, this is quite intuitive.

For a verb as *sehen*, *schauen* or *gucken*, it might be not.

> Ich schaue auf die Uhr.

*I look at the clock.*

You are **aiming** your view on the watch. That's why you need a direction here.

> Ich schaue mal im Schuppen nach dem Besen.

*I will check the shed for the broom then.*

You go to the shed and check for the broom **in there**. That's why you need a place here.