# "auf dem" vs. "auf das"?

Tags: grammatical-case, usage, wechselpraeposition

As a German native speaker, I know that both of the following sentences are correct (at least in daily language):

> Ich speichere meine Dateien auf dem Netzwerklaufwerk.
>
> Ich komme nicht auf das Netzwerklaufwerk.

As far as I can say (I'm not an expert), in both sentences "auf dem/das Netzwerklaufwerk" is an "Adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes" (Question-Sentences: "Wo speichere ich meine Dateien?" and "Wohin komme ich nicht").

Am I wrong? Why is one sentence formed with "auf das" and the other with "auf dem"? Do you have an explanation and maybe more examples?

Comment: Closely related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41846/1696).

Comment: You have the answer in your question: **Wo** speichere ich meine Dateien? => **auf dem** Netzwerklaufwerk, **Wohin** komme ich nicht? => **auf das** Netzwerklaufwerk

Comment: Du kannst hier auch auf Deutsch fragen.

Comment: To my ears, "saving" -- *speichern* involves moving the data from wherever it is now to some permanent storage area. So motion with *auf* implies accusative, something like *Ich stelle das Sofa ins Wohnzimmer.* But German and English don't always agree on what counts as motion. @Carsten S: I was wondering about that too.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis @CarstenS Hatte mich das schon gefragt, aber da in StackExchange alle Communities hauptsächlich englisch sind, war ich mir da nie sicher

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the question pronoun corresponding to

> Ich komme nicht auf das Netzwerklaufwerk

is ***wohin***, so it's rather a determination of the **direction** than of location. This makes the difference because the prepositions

> an, auf, hinter, in, neben, über, unter, vor, zwischen

are called [***Wechselpräposition***](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/wechselpr%C3%A4positionen-3/l-40581904/gr-40585492) and can [govern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_government) either the dative or the accusative, changing their meaning. When they describe a location (as in *auf dem Netzlaufwerk speichern – wo?*), they govern the dative. If they are used to indicate a location (*auf das Netzlaufwerk kommen – wohin?*), they go with the accusative.

As a native speaker, you will intuitively understand the difference between *Ich gehe auf dem Boot* (dative) and *Ich gehe auf das Boot* (accusative).* You might also have heard the verb *kommen* getting an insinuating meaning when used with a *Wechselpräposition* governing the dative (see no. 17 [here](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kommen#bedeutungen)): *Ich komme auf das Sofa* (accusative, direction, standard meaning) vs. *Ich komme auf dem Sofa* (dative, location, insinuating meaning).

---

*This example is similar to tofro's, but better comparable to the original sentences because it's neuter as well and hence uses the same articles.

Answer (score 1):

Das ist dasselbe wie

> Ich fahre in die Stadt

vs.

> Ich fahre in der Stadt

Manche Präpositionen des Ortes können sowohl im Akkusativ (wenn eine Bewegung auf etwas zu gemeint ist) als auch im Dativ (wenn eine Bewegung innerhalb eines bestimmten Bereichs - oder ein statischer Zustand) gemeint ist.